# Как правильно сделать декомпозицию в golang?

Tags: golang

Как без привязки к git сделать декомпозицию golang проекта и чтобы он мог находиться вне $GOPATH. К примеру:

```
my_custom_directory
    └── src
        ├── main.go
        ├── pkg_1
        │   ├── file_1.go
        │   └── file_2.go
        └── pkg_2
            ├── file_1.go
            ├── file_2.go
            └── file_3.go
```

Где src/pkg_1/file_1 содержит импорт какого-либо внешнего модуля.

Как правильно поставить imports во всех файлах, если относительные пути нельзя использовать в новой версии golang? Может быть как-то сделать packages модулями?

Хотелось бы сделать все это без привязки к git-репозиторию в каком-либо github/gitlab а локально на компьютерею.

Возможно это все звучит как типичная просьба заказчика, но неужели в golang все жестко привязано к $GOPATH и git?

Comment: replace прописать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go.mod:

```
module Test1

go 1.17

require (
    SomeProjectName/ModuleName v1.0.0
)

replace SomeProjectName/ModuleName => ../ModuleName
```

upd. исправил пример.