# Работа с локальными модулями в go

Tags: golang, модули

Есть папка go

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в которой также есть две папки - greeting и hello

**greeting.go**

```
package greeting

import "fmt"

func Hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello!")
}
func Hi() {
    fmt.Println("Hi!")
}
```

**hello.go**

```
package main

import gr "greet/greeting"

func main() {
    gr.Hello()
    gr.Hi()
}
```

Получается, я хочу импортировать greeting в hello, но ошибка в том, что в GOPATH указан путь по умолчанию, в диск C, у меня же, проект go находится на диске D.
Конечно можно создать терминал и в нем указать путь в GOPATH для go, но придется каждый раз менять GOPATH для каждого нового созданного терминала.
Второй вариант - go.mod. Но при инициализации go.mod

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

он ищет пакет в GOROOT пути.

Как можно решить эту проблему, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1401563/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-golang/1401572#1401572

Comment: Пишет что
package command-line-arguments
        imports greeting
        imports greeting: import cycle not allowed

Comment: Циклический импорт невозможен :)

Comment: Но его же там нет)

Comment: Покажите содержимое go.mod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**greeting/greeting.go**

```
package greeting

import "fmt"

func Hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello!")
}
func Hi() {
    fmt.Println("Hi!")
}
```

**greeting/go.mod**

```
module greeting

go 1.17
```

**hi/main.go**

```
package main

import gr "greet/greeting"

func main() {
    gr.Hello()
    gr.Hi()
}
```

**hi/go.mod**

```
module Test

go 1.17
require (
    greet/greeting v0.0.0 // indirect
)

replace greet/greeting => ../greeting
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все работает! спасибо большое

Comment: можно вопрос, получается, в каждом пакете нужно создать свой go.mod файл?

Comment: The **module root directory** is the directory that **contains the go.mod file.** https://go.dev/ref/mod
В пакете - нет, но пакет нельзя и подключить из внешней папки, а в модуле - можно :)